# Is the Asp.net Identity security stamp a secret or can it be made public?

Tags: security, asp.net-identity

Is sending the security stamp that ASP.Net Identity creates to the end user in an email a security hole in some fashion? E.g. can a hacker glean anything meaningful from it to attack my application?

---

**Details**

I've setup an application to send password reset emails to the end user upon request. In addition to the standard link to reset the password I also send another link that tells the user to click it if they did **not** request a password reset. When this other link is clicked I record details in the database about the incident and in order to prevent double clicks I want to use the security stamp as a check. Immediately after saving this information I reset the security stamp of the user in question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have implemented your security stamp.

Default Identity just generates a GUID for a stamp. In this case it's no less secure than exposing a user's ID. As a related issue you want to make sure nobody can externally manipulate the stamp.

If your stamp is calculated and it uses part of the user's identity (such as email, roles, name) you want to make sure that it's hashed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a secret, unless you've changed how Security Stamps are issued.

The user's UserId and Security Stamp are encrypted into the Application Cookie. Any data inside this cookie that you expose exposes info that could help an attacker hack the key you're using on your server. In our application we never expose User Ids, which are the easiest thing to let slip, but we definitely don't expose Security Stamps.

That said, without the attacker determining your key it would be hard for them to provide a fake Security Stamp - unless you not only exposed it but also read from the value you exposed. Then it would be very easy to attack your web application.